# Avoid Deadlock - Process

Tags: c

I want to know how can I avoid a deadlock in this program

```
void transfer(int from, into to, double amount) {
     sem_t *sem_from, *sem_to;
     sem_from=get_sem(from); //function that obtains the semaphore from bank account argument
     sem_to=get_sem(to);
     sem_wait(sem_from);
     sem_wait(sem_to);
     withdraw(from, amount); 
     deposit(to, amount); 
     sem_post(sem_to);
     sem_post(sem_from);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423418/deadlock-transfer-program

Comment: Always test the return value of system calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a deadlock by always taking the locks in the same order.

Since your account numbers are integers, there's a natural order to lock them in: smallest (or largest) first. (And release in the opposite order.)

Something like:

```
if (from < to) {
  sem_one = get_sem(from);
  sem_two = get_sem(to);
} else if (to < from) {
  sem_one = get_sem(to);
  sem_two = get_sem(from);
} else {
  // weird self transfer, deal with it
}
sem_wait(sem_one);
sem_wait(sem_two);
// process transaction
sem_post(sem_two);
sem_post(sem_one);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably taking locks in different order. Let's say that in thread 1 `from` is equal to 1 and `to` is equal to 2. In thread 2 `from` is equal to 2 and `to` is equal to 1. Then you have something like this:

time 1: thread 1: lock 1 thread 2: lock 2

time 2: thread 1: cannot lock2, thread 2: cannot lock 1

deadlock.